# Is "A history of Philosophy - from the Pre-Socratics to Plotinus" by Frederick Copleston useful for a beginner?

Tags: reference-request

I have read Plato' dialogues and have some general knowledge about philosophy thanks to Michael Sugrue's lectures on youtube. Is this book useful for a beginner like me?

Comment: Frederick Copleston's A History of Philosophy is simply a fabulous exemplar of philosophical thinking, instructively narrating the philosophical odyssey, pointing out the underlying questions and making interesting connections among ideas. Try to come by all the nine volumes of the series (there are also two additional volumes).

Comment: Thanks for a reply. I’m sure it’s an excellent book but is it suitable for general reader, beginner like me who has general knowledge of philosophy?

Comment: I think so. Any high school student having enthusiasm for philosophy could read it with pleasure.

Comment: Of course Copleston is a classic in the history of philosophy. But because you started reading some main primary sources I would recommend to continue with further primary(!) sources like Xenophanes, Parmenides, Aristotle, Plotinus, Augustinus, Abaelard, Thomas Aquinas, Descartes, Leibniz, Hume, Kant, ..., Popper.

Comment: Thanks for a reply, I think I will continue reading primary sources, i just need secondary literature to better understand complex topics and philosophical texts like Aritotles’s “Metaphysics”.